# Enabling extrusion sharpens selected object

Tags: modeling, extrude

[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhmXf.jpg)

When I try to extrude this spinned object, it immediately makes it sharp and then after pulling the extrude marker out, it makes a seam and then makes an odd shape. I tried to right click and merge vertices by distance, but it has no effect and this still happens.

Comment: If at first you start extruding it, of course it gets sharp. Before pulling it out the new edge is very close to the old one you start from. Actually, that's what many people do to sharpen round edges caused by the _Subdivision Surface Modifier_. They add edge loops or knife cuts etc. close to the round edge to make it sharper. And what do you mean by "makes an odd shape" after pulling out?

Comment: Hi, the problem i'm facing is that the extrude tool just immediately snaps to a direction as seen in the video. If I press z and then extrude, the direction problem is solved, but the odd shape I am talking about still exists. It is a bulged type shape that appears. 
[Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/5NYFUXz)

Comment: Well, the snapping to a direction is the intended behaviour - the tool extrudes in the median direction of the face(s) when using _Extrude Region_. The bulge is caused by the _Subdivision Surface Modifier_. With very few geometry it gets rounded a lot because there are not enough edges preserving a different shape - hence people add edge loops, cuts or simply more geometry to avoid that. As soon as you finish the extrusion and start a new one, this new edge will sharpen the bulge end. If this irritates you, you can disable the subsurf modifier while editing the mesh.

Comment: Hi, I've been just playing around and I didn't really find a fix for this, I added more geometry, tried to work with loop cuts, it doesn't work, but I just selected the bulged part and moved it down and it looks normal again.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing to make it look "normal" again or what you mean by normal.

Answer (score 0):

The video shows the typical (and not incorrect) bulging that happens when you have a closed tubular object with subdivision surface enabled. To avoid that, delete the face at the end so that the mesh is open on the side where you extrude it. If you want to leave it closed, add a loopcut to sharpen / flatten the bulge. It also helps with the fixed direction so you don't have to hit <kbd>Z</kbd> to unlock it. The face normal indicates the direction of the extrude, without it it is not locked at the beginning of the extrusion.

[image: open / close mesh]

[image: loop cut]